# iPhone add event for a button in different class

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a view controller let's call it "View Controller A".
I have a different class(derived from NSObject and in .h and .m pair), let's call this class "B".
From a function of "B" I am adding a button in "A" using addSubView.
The button is getting added but now I want to attach an event to this newly button.
I am using

```
[newButton addTarget:self etc. etc.]
```

but it isn't working.

I don't want to declare the event in View Controller "A".
Is there any way to get rid of this?

Thanks all for reading this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[newButton addTarget:viewControllerA etc. etc.]
```

**EDIT:** More complete version:

```
[newButton addTarget:viewControllerA action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

This assumes that class B has a reference to View Controller A named `viewControllerA`. It also assumes that View Controller A has implemented the method:

```
- (void)buttonAction:(id)sender;
```

**EDIT 2:** So this is what you want:

```
[newButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I assume you already have that and I assume that the reason it doesn't work is because you have a method that looks something like this:

```
+ (void)addButtonToController:(UIViewController *)controller;
```

That's a class method. There is no `self` in a class method. One possible solution is to make it a singleton class and simply change the method to:

```
- (void)addButtonToController:(UIViewController *)controller;
```

You would call that method using:

```
[[ClassB sharedInstance] addButtonToController:controller];
```

If you don't know how to create a singleton class I could update my answer a third time to include that. :)

**EDIT 3:** I still think my original answer is the correct one. You don't have to implement `- (void)buttonAction:(id)sender;` in every controller. You could use inheritance or a category, to have access to this method in every controller without having to implement it for every controller. If you need help with this let me know.

Comment: But by doing so, the viewControllerA needs to have that method(selector method) and I don't want to add the method in viewControllerA.
:(

Comment: @Guru To not violate MVC `viewControllerA` needs to have that method. If you don't care for MVC, which I think you should, you could have class B (or any other class) handle the event, but that would be bad design and I don't recommend it.

Comment: Let's say I have 26 viewController from "A" to "Z" and I have static method in class "B" which adds that button to the calling class like "A", "B" etc..

It means I have a class "B" which adds the same button to all the classes, the button do the same thing on all viewcontroller hence I don't want to write the
 - (void)buttonAction:(id)sender;
to all those 26 classes hence I wanted a solution where I can define the buttonAction in the class "B" itself and I can use the button from anywhere without writing any additional code.

This was what I wanted.
:)

Comment: @Guru I can see why you would want to do that, so I updated my answer to include how to do that. However I'm still not convinced that I like the design.